# Failed to load Qt platform plugin cocoa

Tags: macos, qt, cocoa, meshlab

I am using MacOS Sierra (version: 10.12.3). I am trying to use Meshlabserver from the command line, but I am getting the following error:

This application failed to start because it could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "cocoa"
in "".

I do not know much about working in the command line. Can anyone help me how to solve this?

[image]

Thanks a lot
Sundar